# Need help on how to use Cassandra Kafka Connector

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need help on this github code:
https://github.com/castagna/kafka-connect-cassandra

The goal of this code is to receive datas from Apache Kafka, and then add them into Cassandra database automatically (It is called a connector).

I was able to compile it normally, but there is no much infos on how to use it.

My only concern now is to know what is the format of messages that I have to send to this connector using a JSON format, so he can interpret it and add to Cassandra database.

The function responsible to put datas to Cassandra DB:

```
@Override
public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> records) {
    if (records.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    final SinkRecord first = records.iterator().next();
    final int recordsCount = records.size();
    log.trace("Received {} records. First record kafka coordinates:({}-{}-{}). Writing them to Cassandra...", recordsCount, first.topic(), first.kafkaPartition(), first.kafkaOffset());
    try {
        writer.write(records);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Write of {} records failed, remainingRetries={}", records.size(), remainingRetries, e);
        if (remainingRetries == 0) {
            throw new ConnectException(e);
        } else {
            writer.closeQuietly();
            initWriter();
            remainingRetries--;
            // context.timeout(10000); // TODO: make this a configurable option
            throw new RetriableException(e);
        }
    }
    remainingRetries = config.maxRetries;
}
```

**What I have tried:**

Keyspace and table:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};
use demo;

create table products (id int, product varchar, price float, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Format of message used (JSON):

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"}, {"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"product"}, {"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"price"}],"optional":false,"name":"orders"},"payload":{"id":1, "product": "test", "price":120}}
```

And finally config file (cassandra-sink.properties):

```
name=cassandra-sink-products
connector.class=com.github.castagna.kafka.connect.cassandra.CassandraSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=testTopic

cassandra.host=127.0.0.1
cassandra.keyspace.name=demo

auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
```

Your help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That connector is pretty old - you want to get a currently-maintained connector e.g.

- https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-cassandra
- https://www.confluent.io/hub/datastax/kafka-connect-dse

To use Kafka Connect you specify a configuration file and pass this as an argument to Kafka Connect when you run it (or pass it to its REST API).

I'd suggest reviewing [this talk](http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect) on what Kafka Connect is and how to use it, and [this quickstart](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html) for examples on how to run it. You can find more information about Kafka Connect [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I already know about the first one, unfortunately it is limited only for 30 days ... I want to try the second one, but there is no much infos about the configuration file and an example of message format to send :(

Comment: @PicsouGamer It would definitely be nice if there was more documentation for the Datastax connector, but I did find there is more information on their website at https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/index.html